# mod_rewrite to get query string PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I asked a question a while ago to sort out my directory structure and you all solved my problem (Thanks!) but im now changing this site to another server and rewrite rule does not work. I cannot find the problem. I sent a support ticked to the hosting and they said:

> If that statement doesnt work then it will be either incorrect, or not designed to work with the web server we are running. We use Apache version 2.2
>
> The manual for mod_rewrite for apache 2.2 is here...
>
> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

I have looked over and over this manual and I dont see what the difference is for my rule!

I want to get the text after the `url/bank/` and send it to `url/bank/index.php` as a parameter called `title`! This rule does work on my other server space so I know that the rule does work!

The rule is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bank/([^/.]+)/?$ bank/index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Any pointers would be great!

Thanks
Ian

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Do you get an Apache error? Is the .htaccess file supported/being read?

Comment: Stupid question but it has already happened to me : Are you sure the Apache conf allow it (no `AllowOverride None` for your rewrited website dir in the config ?)

Comment: I have a feeling that the .htaccess file is being overriden by the root .htaccess file which contains a load of wordpress installation data!

Supprt have said that it is all enabled! I get a 404 saying that the directory is not found but on other hosts its fine!

Comment: I have just put a .htaccess file in a new directory and created a simple 301 and it works fine! Im not sure what the problem is now!
If you go to http://www.compensation-claims.org/bank/ the links down the side should work! i know that my page is working because if i try http://www.compensation-claims.org/bank/index.php?title=ppiit works find! it is a problem with the .htaccess file! How can I check that it is even getting to the .htaccess file?

Comment: that link should say http://www.compensation-claims.org/bank/index.php?title=ppi

Comment: Sorry I should have put this here but I created another question!

In my root .htaccess file wordpress has put this:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

and in a sub directory I have a .htaccess file that says:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bank/([^/.]+)/?$ bank/index.php?title=$1 [L]

Answer (score 2):

instead of:

```
RewriteRule ^bank/([^/.]+)/?$ bank/index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

try:

```
RewriteBase /bank/
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?title=$1 [L]
```