# Wordpress mod_rewrite is stopping my query string from working

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

In my root `.htaccess` file wordpress has put this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and in a sub directory I have this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bank/([^/.]+)/?$ bank/index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

My `.htaccess` file works on other servers where it is in the root! I now get a 404 error when there is anything after `bank/` but I know that the code in `bank/index.php` is working as `bank/index.php?title=ppi` works fine.

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200017/modrewrite-to-get-query-string-php

Answer (score 0):

Either try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^bank/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Or put your rule into the .htaccess file in the document root before Wordpress’ rule.